# UFW port forwarding does not work with my coturn set up

Tags: webrtc, ufw, coturn

I am trying to receive data on port 443 and forward that to my coturn server listening to port 5349.

I want this set up so that my webRTC app can connect over 443 but without my coturn server having root access(for privilege port 443).

In my `/etc/ufw/before.rules` I have below entries

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 5349
COMMIT
```

When I test my turn setup at https://test.webrtc.org/ using 443 port I get:
`Udp disabled`
`Relay connectivity timed out`
`Reflexive connectivity timed out`

But using using port 5349 it seems to work.

I have all needed ports open in ufw. I tried with `ufw disabled` too.
Do I need to add any other changes for port forwarding like adding entry OUTPUT(which I don't know how to add, though).
Do I need to add the rule entry for IPv6 too (`/etc/ufw/before6.rules`)?

Answer (score 0):

I added these to the before.rules file

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 5349
-A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 5349


:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 5349
-A OUTPUT -o lo -p udp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 5349

COMMIT
```

I am not sure if it is ok. But at the moment this seems to work. I am still open for suggestion. Please give me suggestions to improve what I have done so far